# How do I combine two features of different dimension?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, feature-extraction

Let us consider the problem of text classification. So if the document is represented as Bag of words , then  we will have an n dimensional feature , where n- number of words in the document. Now if the I decide that I also want to use the document length as feature , then the dimension of this feature alone( length ) will be one. So how do I combine to use both the features (length and Bag of words). Should consider the feature now as 2 dimensional( n-dimensional vector(BOW) and 1-dimensional feature(length). If this wont work , How do I combine the features. Any pointers on this will also be helpful ?

Comment: Just appending the feature vectors end to end is the basic solution.

Answer (score 4):

This statement is a little ambiguous: "So if the document is represented as Bag of words, then we will have an n dimensional feature, where n- number of words in the document."

My interpretation is that you have a column for each word that occurs in your corpus (probably restricted to some dictionary of interest), and for each document you have counted the number of occurrences of that word. Your number of columns is now equal to the number of words in your dictionary that appear in ANY of the documents. You also have a "length" feature, which could be a count of the number of words in the document, and you want to know how to incorporate it into your analysis.

A simple approach would be to divide the number of occurrences of a word by the total number of words in the document.

This has the effect of scaling the word occurrences based on the size of the document, and the new feature is called a 'term frequency'. The next natural step is to weight the term frequencies to compensate for terms that are more common in the corpus (and therefore less important). Since we give HIGHER weights to terms that are LESS common, this is called 'inverse document frequency', and the whole process is called “Term Frequency times Inverse Document Frequency”, or tf-idf. You can Google this for more information.

---

It's possible that you are doing word counts in a different way -- for example, counting the number of word occurrences in each paragraph (as opposed to each document). In that case, for each document, you have a word count for each paragraph, and the typical approach is to merge these paragraph-counts using a process such as Singular Value Decomposition.